# Can't change font awesome icon with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I created a code that changes the class of an svg icon. Using Chrome's inspect I can see that it has sucessfully changed svg class from 'fa-circle' to 'fa-check-circle as intended. However the icon remains the same and nothing happens.

```
 function mouseOverEffect() {
                //JQUERY, FIND A VANILLA JS SOLUTION?
                $("#inbox-circle").mouseover(function() {                    
                    console.log($(this).hasClass('fa-circle'))
                    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-circle')) {                                              
                        $(this).removeClass( "fa-circle" ).addClass( "fa-check-circle" )

                    } 
                });
            }
```

Is there something about svg's that I'm missing?
The complete function is here: https://pastebin.com/3Dyv25xf

Comment: Are you sure you are able to target the correct element ? Are you using dev tools to verify the exact element ? I was testing here https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery and you can change the icon by changing the classes needed.
Sometimes the 1st class (like a collection class) can be wrong, fore instance, some icons need "fab" other "fal" or "fas" etc. There are many, and to be able to change you need to change both classes not only the icon class itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think jquery is using setAttribute() for attaching property value to node. For svg we have to use setAttributeNS() method.

Can you try the below code

```
$(this).removeClass( "fa-circle" ) ;// After this code
//.addClass( "fa-check-circle" ) // comment this code

$(this)[0].setAttributeNS(null, "class", "far fa-check-circle" ); // add this line
```

Comment: This makes the first icon disappear but the check-circle doesn't appear.

Comment: oh , since setAttributeNs() method is replacing the previous class value with new one, i think you just need to include "far" to the class value. so the final code should be $(this)[0].setAttributeNS(null, "class", "far fa-check-circle" )

Comment: can you try with 'fa' instead of 'far'

Comment: You can see example code  in this link https://jsfiddle.net/SyamKumarD/xLtag1mq/9/

Comment: I'm really at a loss here. As you can see here (https://gfycat.com/spiffyharmoniousfritillarybutterfly), the markup changes as intended but the icon does not...

Comment: why don't you use <span></span> tag or <div style="display:inline-block"></div> tag instead of <svg> tag ?

Comment: You can also try to reduce the size of your svg viewBox property value from "0 0 512 512" to "0 0 20 20" or "0 0 10 10"

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS pseudo-elements and pseudo-class `:hover`. CSS incurs less processing power than JS/jQ, it's simpler to write and maintain, and IMO performs better. Refer to **[CSS Pseudo-Elements | Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)**

**HTML**

```
<i class="icon circle"></i>
```

**See Demo for CSS**

```css
:root {
  font: 5vw/1.2 Verdana;
}

.icon::before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}

.circle::before {
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f111";
}

.circle:hover::before {
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f058";
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class='inbox'>
  <li class="row inbox-item">
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2"><i class="icon circle" style="color:red"></i></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-6">test </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">07-21-19</div>
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2 task-actions"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li class="row inbox-item">
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2"><i class="icon circle" style="color:gold"></i></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-6">test </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">07-24-19</div>
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2 task-actions"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li class="row inbox-item">
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2"><i class="icon circle" style="color:blue"></i></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-6">test </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">07-29-19</div>
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2 task-actions"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
  </li>
  <li class="row inbox-item">
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2"><i class="icon circle" style="color:gold"></i></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-6">test </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">07-25-19</div>
    <div class="col-2 col-lg-2 task-actions"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I try to use pseudo-elements my circles don't render at all... I just get some weird rectangles. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: You have to use all of the code in this answer then when it's successful you modify it progressively to integrate it into your code. My answer is barebones integration to the code you have provided in your answer. When you tried pseudo-elements did you apply it exactly how it is in this answer? I saw the gif (not very helpful since it is not code) and from what I saw the svg has no `.far` class which is required.